# Boot Linux USB Drive From USB Floppy

Tags: linux, usb, boot, bios

I have a USB drive on which I want to install Arch Linux (using the installer, not unetbootin or something similar, as I want the drive to be persistent.) The computer from which I want to boot this USB supports booting from a USB floppy, not a normal drive. Is there any way for me to make a USB floppy on another drive and use that to boot the normal USB drive? Thanks.

Comment: In theory you could boot a small linux from the floppy, with a USB driver, and have more stuff on the USB drive. I've done that with DOS  in the past. Maybe the bigger linux on the USB flash drive could be started via an executable after booting a smaller linux from the floppy drive.  Otherwise, well, regardless, I think the USB External floppy drive is limited to 1.44MB!

Answer (score 0):

A while back I came across some nice software called Plop (an unlikely name).

http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html

In essence it's a boot manager that can be installed to pretty much anything that can boot (usually a CDROM) and will then let you boot off anything else - even USB drives when your system doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Plop from previous answer is a great solution.

Is it that your BIOS doesn't support booting from a USB drive? If that is the case read ["How To Boot From USB And CDROM Without BIOS Support"](http://www.megaleecher.net/Boot_USB_Without_Motherboard_Support).

Can't you boot from the cd-rom ? Or bring your own external usb cd-rom (no power-just usb) and boot from a cd.

Some resources you might find useful:

[Install GNU/Linux without any CD, floppy, USB-key, nor any other removable media](http://marc.herbert.free.fr/linux/win2linstall.html)

[Booting Knoppix from a USB Pendrive via Floppy](http://linuxgazette.net/116/okopnik1.html)

[Booting from Floppy with USB](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Booting_from0.html)